# Generate a LTPA2 token from SSO Login in a NodeJS Application

Tags: node.js, websphere, single-sign-on, websphere-liberty, ltpa

I have a node application which is SSO enabled. I need to call some REST API's which are implemented in a IBM Websphere Java project with Liberty Profile. For security reasons, the REST API's are expecting a LTPA(LTPA2) Token to be sent from the NodeJS .

How can this be implemented?

Answer (score -2):

LTPA tokens are a WebSphere proprietary thing, so that might be tricky.  If any API's for constructing them exist, they are probably in Java.  If you can find out more about what authentication scheme the WebSphere side is expecting (Basic-auth, saml, open-id connect, socialLogin, etc.) there is probably another way to authenticate and authorize that does not involve an LTPA token.